# Importing Unmanaged Solution from Dev does not remove Field from Form added in QA

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

In all environments, there is a field MXM_RemoveMe we want gone from the Account "Information" Form (one of the Account's OOTB Managed Forms, but of course we've customized it on our own a lot by now)

**In Dev, I remove MXM_RemoveMe** from the Account "Information" Form.

I put that Form in an **Unmanaged solution in Dev, export and import into QA. Publish all**.

**Problem:** but the "MXM_RemoveMe" field is STILL on the form in QA.

What could cause this? Do we have to manually remove fields from Forms in all environments? I don't think that's the case normally.

I've verified this behavior in a specific test after the fact. If I add a field to the Account form in QA... then export/import from Dev that Form (Unmanaged) WITHOUT the field... it still stays in QA! I encourage everyone else reading this to do this simple test themselves and see the same behavior I see.

How should this be handled/understood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because the form itself is **managed**. The system simply adds fields to the form on import and does not simply overwrite unmanaged changes any more. In older versions of Dynamics CRM this did not work this way though.

When you prefer to continue working with **unmanaged** solutions (I feel there are valid reasons to do so), a best practice would be to always copy managed forms first and modify, export and import the copy instead of it.

The copy would be in its entirety an unmanaged form. Up to now I have never seen issues with those forms when imported in target environments in an unmanaged state.

Comment: Hmm this appears to be the issue: the "Active" Solution layer in QA is not simply being entirely updated and taking what Dev had (for this Form e.g. formxml formjson). I expected "Active"/Unmanaged layer to entirely overwrite each other... am I mistaken? ** when importing a Unmanaged solution

Comment: This [note on MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/update-solutions#overwrite-customizations-option) suggests this does not work anymore for forms.

Comment: Very strange! At the point in our implementation... we're stuck supporting at least 1 Managed form. Which like you said, doesn't seem to remove fields. It will change position of fields/new ones (I tested), but not remove. I think for my own workflow, I will always first click "Remove active customizations" on the Managed Form when I know I'm deploying changes in my Unmanaged solution to that Unmanaged Form. To be safe/ensure I effectively replace the Unmanaged/Active stuff.

Comment: I agree; I specifically tested an UnManaged form, removing a field, importing in Unmanaged solution to QA -- and the field truly was removed which is good. So UnManaged Form vs Managed Form leads to different behavior of importing Unmanaged changes.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong here but this might be changed in the modern make.powerapps.com compared to how it worked in the classic import experience. You might have the option to overwrite your customizations there(not recommended).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/update-solutions#overwrite-customizations-option

Probably the safest way is to manually go about and delete the components.

Could have to do with solution layering and using the accounts OOTB managed form. Usually, id say it is better to use a custom form

Comment: Yes it appears due to Account>Information being Managed form, and thus Solution layering/behavior of Active layer was different. It was not simply replacing that Active/Unmanaged layer of the Managed Information form. So it would not remove fields. Strange to me. I plan to factor this into my workflow by clicking "Remove active customizations" on any Managed Forms I intend to deploy over (from Dev to QA using an Unmanaged solution).